# How do i query percentages in a select tag

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to get the percentages of the industry_id compared to the adtype_id. So the example below for industry id 2, It should be 1/3 and 2/3 for a total of 100%. I get the records 1 and 2 but how do i get the total count of industry id using this select query is what i am having trouble with. This part of the code is not correct `select count(*) from ads` This is giving output of all the records of the column i just want total record specific to the id of the industry id .

```
  adtype_id   industry_id
   2                2
   3                2
   3                2

result i want:  1/3, 2/3
```

---

```
  $intantype = Ad::
                    join('industries', 'industries.id', 'ads.industry_id')
                    ->join('adtypes', 'adtypes.id', 'ads.adtype_id')
                     ->where('ads.industry_id', $id)
                    ->Select('ads.adtype_id',DB::raw('count(*) *100 / (select count(*) from ads)    as total '), 'industryname')
                    ->groupBy('adtype_id','industryname')
                    ->get();
```

Comment: I read this twice, and still don't understand your question.

Comment: `1/3` and `2/3` needs to be elaborated

Comment: Let me see if I understood this correctly: you want to know what percentage of an `industry_id` each `adtype_id` makes up? As in, `industry_id` of value `2` is made up of two ad types (`2` and `3`), where `adtype_id = 2` makes up 1/3 and `adtype_id = 3` makes up 2/3?

Comment: @dqureshiumar so basically i want to group the columns industry_id and  1/3 and 2/3 come from adtype_id out of 100% 1 adtype / 3 total adtype records for industry_id 2

Comment: @El_Vanja correct

Comment: @KIKOSoftware i am struggling to word it but El_Vanja  said what i was trying to say

Comment: Yes, I get it now. It's about the number of occurrences of a certain `adtype_id` value for each `industry_id`. Why not do this in two queries, in the first you get the total of occurrences and in the second the occurrences per value? You can then use PHP to computer the percentage.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware i guess i can do it that way, ill give it a true.